# Stop Camera up movement

Tags: unity

I am developing 3D game , the main camera is child of player.

When player jumps camera too gets move up with player as its child of player.Is there anyway to stop this behavior?

The only thing I can guess is to make camera separate gameobject and let it follow player

**EDIT**
After applying @Everless Drop 41's script, here is what main problem arises

[image]

Comment: Another way would be to keep them together but change the position of the camera as the player jumps and comes back down.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the camera follow the player, but you will want an offset so the player is still seen

I have a script that makes this fairly easy and can be used on other things too.

## [CameraFollow.cs](https://gist.github.com/EverlessDrop41/0b55a04378d96c903895)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform target;

    public bool X, Y, Z;

    public float XOffset, YOffset, ZOffset;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(
            (X ? target.position.x + XOffset : transform.position.x),
            (Y ? target.position.y + YOffset : transform.position.y),
            (Z ? target.position.z + ZOffset : transform.position.z));
        //Use of conditional operator
    }

}
```

### How to use the script

---

1. In the unity project create a new script:

[image: Create Script]

2. Name that script `CameraFollow.cs` This could be different but make sure to change the class name if you don't use CameraFollow.cs

[image: Name Script]

3. Double click the script to open in your editor (Probably MonoDevelop) and paste my code, be sure to name the class correctly if you used a different filename

[image: Paste in content]

4. Add the script to the camera object. In the hierarchy click on the camera, then click on on `Add Component` then search for the name of the script (CameraFollow.cs), press enter when the follow script is highlighted

[image: Add component to camera]

5. Set the target, in your case the player. Either click on the circle and select the player from the window that pops up or drag the player object into the target parameter.

[image: Set target position]

6. Adjust the values to suit you

   - X - Follow on the X axis
   - Y - Same as X but on Y axis
   - Z - Same as X but on Z axis
   - X Offset - Amount to offset this position compared to target position on the X axis
   - Y Offset - Same as X offset but on Y axis
   - Z Offset - Same as X offset but on Z axis

[image: Adjust Values]

Comment: How would the op use your script?

Comment: Very simple, will add the intructions on my answer now

Comment: I think you have an hidden feature: disable one offset programmatically when needed, namely, when the character is jumping, disable the y offset and re-enable it when he's back on the ground. This way the y is not updated when the player is jumping. Or something like that.

Comment: Alexandre Vaillancourt , nice idea, never thought of it in that way.

Comment: this works well if player and camera moving in same axis, when player is moving in curve direction the camera does not work as expected

Comment: @EverlessDrop41added image to explain better,plz check in edit

Comment: Sorry I've taken some time to reply, I will check tomorrow, (it's late where I am right now) but I think you can do a similar thing to the position but use rotation values, I'll check it tomorrow